# Having multiple Owl Carousels on a Shopify page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, owl-carousel-2

I'm writing a homepage for my business website. I encountered a problem after inserting a second Owl Carousel. The second slider is showing up fine but first one somehow disappeared. When I removed the second Carousel, the first one came back. I figured it has to do with giving the divs specific IDs or classes but no matter how I tried I can't seem to make them work.

I tried giving them specific class such as

div class="owl-one owl-carousel owl-theme" and div class="owl-two owl-carousel owl-theme"

As well as ids

div id="owl-one" class="owl-carousel owl-theme"

and div id="owl-two" class="owl-carousel owl-theme"

And changed the script to

$('.owl-one .owl-slideImg .owl-theme').owlCarousel({

$('.owl-two .owl-carousel').owlCarousel({

As well as

$('#owl-one .owl-slideImg .owl-theme').owlCarousel({

$('#owl-two .owl-carousel').owlCarousel({

What am I doing wrong? Please help!

Here is the first slider code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0609/1436/8761/t/6/assets/bootstrap-grid.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.theme.default.css">
```

```
<style>

    
    
    .owl-slideImg .owl-nav div{
        position: absolute !important;
        width: 25px !important;
        height: 25px !important; 
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        cursor: pointer; 
        top: 40%;
    }  
    .owl-slideImg .owl-prev {
        left: -55px;    
        opacity: .65;
        background: url(https://www.panpuri.com/asset/frontend/images/right-chevron.svg) !important; 
        background-position: center !important;
        background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
        background-size:  20px 20px !important; 
        transform: rotate(180deg);
        color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) !important;
        transition: .33s all ease-out; 
    } 
    .owl-slideImg .owl-next {
        right: -55px;    
        opacity: .65;
        background: url(https://www.panpuri.com/asset/frontend/images/right-chevron.svg) !important; 
        background-position: center !important;
        background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
        background-size:  20px 20px !important;
        color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) !important;
        transition: .33s all ease-out; 
    }
    .owl-slideImg .owl-prev:hover{ 
        opacity: 1;
    }
    .owl-slideImg .owl-next:hover{ 
        opacity: 1;
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 991px) { /* MOBILE */ 
        .owl-slideImg .slide-img{
            height: 250px;
            background-position: center !important;
            background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
            background-size:  100% auto !important;
        } 
        .owl-slideImg .slide-box-text div{
            padding: 40px; 
        } 
        .owl-slideImg .box-icon-svg{
            display: flex;
            justify-content: end;
        } 
        .box-icon-svg img{
            max-width: 30px;
        }
        
        .container-fluid{
            padding-bottom: 20rem;
            margin-bottom: 20rem;
        }
        .owl-slideImg .owl-nav div{ 
            top: 20%;
        }  
        .owl-slideImg .owl-prev {
            left: 0 !important;     
        } 
        .owl-slideImg .owl-next {
            right: 0 !important;     
        }
    }
    
    @media only screen and (min-width: 992px) { /* PC */ 
        
        .owl-slideImg .slide-box-text{ 
            height:100%; 
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            justify-items: center;
            align-items: center; 
            width:100%;
        } 
        .owl-slideImg .slide-img{
            height: 350px;
            background-position: center !important;
            background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
            background-size: 100% auto !important;
        }
        .owl-slideImg .slide-box-text div{
            width: 60%; 
        }
        .owl-slideImg .box-icon-svg{
            position: absolute;
            right: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            display: flex;
            margin-right: 40px;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
        } 
        .box-icon-svg img{
            max-width: 60px !important;
            margin-top: -20px;
        } 
        .owl-slideImg .owl-item{
            width: 100%;
        }

        .service-header{
            text-align: center;
            justify-content: center;
        }
        .container-fluid{
            padding-bottom: 20rem;
            margin-bottom: 20rem;
        }
    }
</style>

<main>
    <br>

    <br>

    <br>

    <h2 class="service-header">our service</h2>

    <div class="col p-5">
        <div class="row justify-content-center"> 
            <div class="col-xl-8 col-lg-10 col-12 owl-slideImg "> 
                <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
                    <div class="owl-item">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xl-6 col-12 slide-img" style="background: url(https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0609/1436/8761/files/Installation_0702da65-4ad7-42df-9ea6-bca10d7c541a.jpg);"> </div>
                            <div class="col-xl-6 col-12">
                                <div class="slide-box-text">
                                    <div>
                                        Given our versatility and neat craftsmanship in stone installation, we have been providing our service to various leading construction and estate companies in Thailand.
                                    </div>
                                </div> 
                                <div class="box-icon-svg"> 
                                    <h3 class="mr-3">installation</h3>
                                    <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0609/1436/8761/t/6/assets/Installicon.svg?v=1646822679" alt="">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>  
                    <div class="owl-item">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xl-6 col-12 slide-img" style="background: url(https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0609/1436/8761/files/Supply.jpg);"> </div>
                            <div class="col-xl-6 col-12">
                                <div class="slide-box-text">
                                    <div>
                                        With connections and credible sources from both domestic and oversea quarries, we can supply great quality stones that meet your needs and specifications.
                                    </div>
                                </div>  
                                <div class="box-icon-svg"> 
                                    <h3 class="mr-3">supply</h3>
                                    <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0609/1436/8761/t/6/assets/Supplyicon.svg?v=1646822694" alt="">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>  
                    <div class="owl-item">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xl-6 col-12 slide-img" style="background: url(https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0609/1436/8761/files/Restore.jpg);"> </div>
                            <div class="col-xl-6 col-12">
                                <div class="slide-box-text">
                                    <div>
                                        We let our designers draft up a digital rendered image beforehand for any customisation and specifications such as landscaping and counter tops.
                                    </div>
                                </div> 
                                <div class="box-icon-svg"> 
                                    <h3 class="mr-3">design</h3>
                                    <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0609/1436/8761/t/6/assets/Designicon.svg?v=1646822671" alt="">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>  
                    <div class="owl-item">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xl-6 col-12 slide-img" style="background: url(https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0609/1436/8761/files/Design.jpg);"> </div>
                            <div class="col-xl-6 col-12">
                                <div class="slide-box-text">
                                    <div>
                                        With high quality machines, we can provide any finishing and resurfacing process including polishing and honing.
                                    </div>
                                </div>  
                                <div class="box-icon-svg"> 
                                    <h3 class="mr-3">restore</h3>
                                    <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0609/1436/8761/t/6/assets/Restoreicon.svg?v=1646822686" alt="">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>  
                </div>  
            </div>

            <br> 
        </div>
    </div>
</main>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>     
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/owl.carousel.js"></script> 




<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $(".owl-slideImg .owl-theme").owlCarousel({
            center: false,
            loop: true,
            autoplay: true,
            autoplayTimeout: 50000,
            nav: true,
            dots: true, 
            items: 1,
            margin: 40
        });
    });
</script>
```

And this is the second slider code:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" integrity="sha512-tS3S5qG0BlhnQROyJXvNjeEM4UpMXHrQfTGmbQ1gKmelCxlSEBUaxhRBj/EFTzpbP4RVSrpEikbmdJobCvhE3g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css" integrity="sha512-sMXtMNL1zRzolHYKEujM2AqCLUR9F2C4/05cdbxjjLSRvMQIciEPCQZo++nk7go3BtSuK9kfa/s+a4f4i5pLkw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

</head>
<body>

    <br>

    <div class="logoslider">
        <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
            <div class="item">
                <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0609/1436/8761/files/G1_Client-Logo5.jpg" alt="The Ritz Carlton">
            </div>
            
            <div class="item">
                <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0609/1436/8761/files/G1_Client-Logo2.jpg" alt="Phulaybay">
            </div>
            
            <div class="item">
                <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0609/1436/8761/files/G1_Client-Logo6.jpg" alt="Silpakorn">
            </div>
            
            <div class="item">
                <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0609/1436/8761/files/G1_Client-Logo3.jpg" alt="Property Perfect">
            </div>
            
            <div class="item">
                <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0609/1436/8761/files/G1_Client-Logo1.jpg" alt="Thames Valley">
            </div>
            
            <div class="item">
                <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0609/1436/8761/files/G1_Client-Logo4.jpg" alt="The Mall Group">
            </div>
            
            <div class="item">
                <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0609/1436/8761/files/G1_Client-Logo7.jpg" alt="Pirom At Vineyard">
            </div>
            
            <div class="item">
                <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0609/1436/8761/files/G1_Client-Logo8.jpg" alt="NYE Estate">
            </div>
            
            <div class="item">
                <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0609/1436/8761/files/G1_Client-Logo13.jpg" alt="Balcony Thailand">
            </div>
            
            <div class="item">
                <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0609/1436/8761/files/G1_Client-Logo10.jpg" alt="Harbor Laemchabang">
            </div>
            
            <div class="item">
                <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0609/1436/8761/files/G1_Client-Logo12.jpg" alt="Belle Rama 9">
            </div>
            
            <div class="item">
                <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0609/1436/8761/files/G1_Client-Logo9.jpg" alt="Major Development">
            </div>
            
            <div class="item">
                <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0609/1436/8761/files/G1_Client-Logo11.jpg" alt="Gazebo Garden">
            </div>
            
            <div class="item">
                <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0609/1436/8761/files/G1_Client-Logo15.jpg" alt="360 Pano">
            </div>
            
            <div class="item">
                <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0609/1436/8761/files/G1_Client-Logo14.jpg" alt="Anantarakiri">
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

    <br>

    <br>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js" integrity="sha512-bPs7Ae6pVvhOSiIcyUClR7/q2OAsRiovw4vAkX+zJbw3ShAeeqezq50RIIcIURq7Oa20rW2n2q+fyXBNcU9lrw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script> 


    <script type="text/javascript">
            $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
                loop: true,
                autoplay: true,
                nav: false,
                dots: false,
                margin: 40,
                autoplayTimeout: 1500,
                responsive:{
                    0:{
                        items:4
                    },
                    600:{
                        items:8
                    },
                    1000:{
                        items:8
                    }
            }
        
        })

        
    </script>

</body>

<style>
    .logoslider{
        display: flex;
        width: 80%;
        justify-content: center;
        justify-items: center;
        align-items: center; 
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    }

</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

**Owl Carousel One**

```
var owl_carousel_one = $('.owl-carousel-one');
owl_carousel_one.owlCarousel({
    loop: true,
    margin: 30,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplayTimeout: 5000,
    autoplayHoverPause: true,
    smartSpeed: 1000,
    responsive: {
        0: {
            items: 4
        },
        600: {
            items: 8
        },
        1000: {
            items: 8
        }
    }
});
```

**Owl Carousel Two**

```
var owl_carousel_two = $('.owl-carousel-two');
owl_carousel_two.owlCarousel({
    loop: true,
    margin: 30,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplayTimeout: 5000,
    autoplayHoverPause: true,
    smartSpeed: 1000,
    responsive: {
        0: {
            items: 4
        },
        600: {
            items: 8
        },
        1000: {
            items: 8
        }
    }
});
```

Just use these unique classes (.owl-carousel-one, .owl-carousel-two, and so on...) for each owl carousel HTML element. No need for any ID.